# How to call a single service from multiple activity?

Tags: android, service, httpurlconnection

I am new in `android`, previously worked in `ReactJS`. In react it is easy to create back end service in a separate file and access it with the simple `ajax` call.
To call that service in android, i have user `HttpURLConnection`.

It worked but, is there any way to define the `HttpURLConnection` service call in a separate folder in android project and call it from `any of the activity` in android where & when ever you want and `return` the `response` to activity class.

Comment: yes you can create a common class file and set request method and get parameters using the constructor and return the response using listener

Comment: @JayThummar,  is there example regarding  this

Comment: yes i have created using volley and retrofit api if you want to refer this then i will post it in answer

Comment: @JayThummar,      it will be helpfull if you post that

Answer (score 0):

This is the service class which is used for all types of service call like Get,Post,and etc this is the common base class using this we can create other sub class for particular service so we can call it any where

```
public class ServiceCall {

//Error Codes
private final int OK = 200;
private final int NETWORK_ERROR = 9001;
private final int SERVER_ERROR = 9002;
private final int AUTH_FAILURE_ERROR = 9003;
private final int PARSE_ERROR = 9004;
private final int NO_CONNECTION_ERROR = 9005;
private final int TIME_OUT_ERROR = 9006;
private final int UNKNOWN_ERROR = 9007;

private String LOG_TAG = ServiceCall.class.getName();

private String url;
private HashMap<String, String> hashMap;
private IRestApiListener iRestApiListener;
private int requestMethod;
private HashMap<String, File> fileparts;
private boolean show_no_intenet_message = true;
private Context context;

public ServiceCall(Context context, String url, HashMap<String, String> hashMap, IRestApiListener iRestApiListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.url = url;
    this.hashMap = hashMap;
    this.requestMethod = Integer.parseInt(RequestMethod.POST.toString());
    this.iRestApiListener = iRestApiListener;

    //This is an optionl parameter for this project only Fresh Fills
    setExtraParameterInHashMap(this.hashMap);

    //Check network connection
    if (isInernetConnectionIsAvailable()) {
        iRestApiListener.onNetowkisOn();
        RestApiCall();
    } else {
        iRestApiListener.onNoNetwork();
        if (show_no_intenet_message) {
            showNoInternetMessage();
        }
    }

}

public ServiceCall(Context context, String url, HashMap<String, String> hashMap, RequestMethod requestMethod, IRestApiListener iRestApiListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.url = url;
    this.hashMap = hashMap;
    this.iRestApiListener = iRestApiListener;
    this.requestMethod = Integer.parseInt(requestMethod.toString());

    //This is an optionl parameter for this project only Fresh Fills
    setExtraParameterInHashMap(this.hashMap);

    //Check network connection
    if (isInernetConnectionIsAvailable()) {
        iRestApiListener.onNetowkisOn();
        RestApiCall();
    } else {
        iRestApiListener.onNoNetwork();
        if (show_no_intenet_message) {
            showNoInternetMessage();
        }
    }

}

public ServiceCall(Context context, String url, HashMap<String, String> hashMap, HashMap<String, File> fileparts, RequestMethod requestMethod, IRestApiListener iRestApiListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.url = url;
    this.hashMap = hashMap;
    this.fileparts = fileparts;
    this.iRestApiListener = iRestApiListener;
    this.requestMethod = Integer.parseInt(requestMethod.toString());

    //This is an optionl parameter for this project only Fresh Fills
    setExtraParameterInHashMap(this.hashMap);

    //Check network connection
    if (isInernetConnectionIsAvailable()) {
        iRestApiListener.onNetowkisOn();
        UploadImage();
    } else {
        iRestApiListener.onNoNetwork();
        if (show_no_intenet_message) {
            showNoInternetMessage();
        }
    }


}

//This is an optionl parameter for this project only Fresh Fills
private void setExtraParameterInHashMap(HashMap<String, String> map) {
    map.put("apiKey", "Yck8g9]gxo1uXHx[72h?EX:j!VL7l9");
    map.put("langId", "1");
    map.put("version", "1");
}

/**
 * Get ,Post Method call
 */
private void RestApiCall() {

    StringRequest commonRequest = new StringRequest(requestMethod, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "URL " + url + "\n Response : " + response);
            if (iRestApiListener != null) {
                setparsing(response);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Handle your error types accordingly.For Timeout & No
            // connection error, you can show 'retry' button.
            // For AuthFailure, you can re login with user
            // credentials.
            // For ClientError, 400 & 401, Errors happening on
            // client side when sending api request.
            // In this case you can check how client is forming the
            // api and debug accordingly.
            // For ServerError 5xx, you can do retry or handle
            // accordingly.
            int errorCode;
            if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                errorCode = NETWORK_ERROR;
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NetworkError" + error);
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                errorCode = SERVER_ERROR;
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ServerError" + error);
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                errorCode = AUTH_FAILURE_ERROR;
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "AuthFailureError" + error);
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                errorCode = PARSE_ERROR;
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ParseError" + error);
            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                errorCode = NO_CONNECTION_ERROR;
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NoConnectionError" + error);
            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                errorCode = TIME_OUT_ERROR;
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TimeoutError" + error);
            } else {
                errorCode = UNKNOWN_ERROR;
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TimeoutError" + error);
            }

            //Log.i(LOG_TAG,"StatusCode" + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
            if (iRestApiListener != null) {
                iRestApiListener.onCallFinish();
                iRestApiListener.onError(new JSONArray());
            }
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + AppClass.preferences.getValueFromPreferance(Preferences.TOKEN));
            Log.d("Logger", "Authorization: " + AppClass.preferences.getValueFromPreferance(Preferences.TOKEN));
            return params;
        }


        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return hashMap;
        }
    };

    commonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, 1, 1));
    AppClass.mVolleyInstance.addToRequestQueue(commonRequest);
}

/**
 * Upload image
 */
private void UploadImage() {

    RestApiMultiPartRequests<String> restApiMultiPartRequest =
            new RestApiMultiPartRequests<String>(url, hashMap, fileparts, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "URL " + url + "\n Response : " + response);
                    if (iRestApiListener != null) {
                        setparsing(response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Handle your error types accordingly.For Timeout & No
                    // connection error, you can show 'retry' button.
                    // For AuthFailure, you can re login with user
                    // credentials.
                    // For ClientError, 400 & 401, Errors happening on
                    // client side when sending api request.
                    // In this case you can check how client is forming the
                    // api and debug accordingly.
                    // For ServerError 5xx, you can do retry or handle
                    // accordingly.
                    int errorCode;
                    if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        errorCode = NETWORK_ERROR;
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NetworkError" + error);
                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        errorCode = SERVER_ERROR;
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ServerError" + error);
                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        errorCode = AUTH_FAILURE_ERROR;
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "AuthFailureError" + error);
                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        errorCode = PARSE_ERROR;
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ParseError" + error);
                    } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        errorCode = NO_CONNECTION_ERROR;
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NoConnectionError" + error);
                    } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                        errorCode = TIME_OUT_ERROR;
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TimeoutError" + error);
                    } else {
                        errorCode = UNKNOWN_ERROR;
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TimeoutError" + error);
                    }

                    //Log.i(LOG_TAG,"StatusCode" + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                    if (iRestApiListener != null) {
                        iRestApiListener.onCallFinish();
                        iRestApiListener.onError(new JSONArray());
                    }
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(AppClass.preferences.getValueFromPreferance(Preferences.TOKEN))) {
                        params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + AppClass.preferences.getValueFromPreferance(Preferences.TOKEN));
                    }

                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    return params;
                }
            };

    restApiMultiPartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, 1, 2));//10000
    AppClass.mVolleyInstance.addToRequestQueue(restApiMultiPartRequest);
}

/**
 * Parse the response
 *
 * @param response
 */
private void setparsing(String response) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(response)) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

            if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).has("status")){
                String status = String.valueOf(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getInt("status"));
                if (status.equals("1")) {
                    iRestApiListener.onCallFinish();
                    iRestApiListener.onResponseTrue(jsonArray);
                } else {
                    iRestApiListener.onCallFinish();
                    iRestApiListener.onResponseFalse(jsonArray);

                }
            }else {
                iRestApiListener.onCallFinish();
                iRestApiListener.onResponseTrue(jsonArray);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            iRestApiListener.onError(new JSONArray());
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Created by Jay
 * Enum return type of service call
 */
public enum RequestMethod {
    DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Request.Method.DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST + "";
        }
    },
    GET {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Request.Method.GET + "";
        }
    },
    POST {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Request.Method.POST + "";
        }
    },
    PUT {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Request.Method.PUT + "";
        }
    },
    DELETE {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Request.Method.DELETE + "";
        }
    },
    HEAD {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Request.Method.HEAD + "";
        }
    },
    OPTIONS {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Request.Method.OPTIONS + "";
        }
    },
    TRACE {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Request.Method.TRACE + "";
        }
    },
    PATCH {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Request.Method.PATCH + "";
        }
    },
}

/**
 * Mutipart Request Calss
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
private class RestApiMultiPartRequests<T> extends Request<T> {

    private final Map<String, String> mStringParts;
    private final Map<String, File> mFileParts;
    private MultipartEntityBuilder mBuilder;
    private final Response.Listener<T> mListener;

    public RestApiMultiPartRequests(String url,
                                    Map<String, String> stringParts,
                                    Map<String, File> fileParts,
                                    Response.Listener<T> listener,
                                    Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
        mStringParts = stringParts;
        mFileParts = fileParts;
        buildMultipartEntity();
    }

    private void buildMultipartEntity() {
        if (mBuilder != null) {
            mBuilder = null;
        }
        mBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        mBuilder.setBoundary("_____" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "_____");
        mBuilder.setCharset(Consts.UTF_8);
        if (mStringParts != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringParts.entrySet()) {
                mBuilder.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), ContentType.create("text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            }
        }

        Log.e("Size", "Size: " + mFileParts.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, File> entry : mFileParts.entrySet()) {
            ContentType imageContentType = ContentType.create("image/*");//MULTIPART_FORM_DATA;
            Log.d("", "Key " + entry.getKey());
            Log.d("", "Value " + entry.getValue());
            Log.d("", "Name " + entry.getValue().getName());
            //"userfile"
            mBuilder.addBinaryBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), imageContentType, entry.getValue().getName());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return mBuilder.build().getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            mBuilder.build().writeTo(bos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            iRestApiListener.onError(new JSONArray());
        }

        return bos.toByteArray();
    }


    public HttpEntity getEntity() {
        return mBuilder.build();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return (Response<T>) Response.success(jsonString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);

    }


}

/**
 * Check network availibility
 *
 * @return
 */
private boolean isInernetConnectionIsAvailable() {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (AppClass.networkConnectivity.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        flag = true;
    } else {
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}

/**
 * Show no internet message
 */
private void showNoInternetMessage() {
    AppClass.snackBarView.snackBarShow(context, context.getString(R.string.nonetwork));
}

/**
 * true , false show internet message or not
 *
 * @param flag
 * @return
 */
public ServiceCall setAllowDisAllowInternetMessage(boolean flag) {
    this.show_no_intenet_message = false;
    return this;
}


public interface IRestApiListener {

    public void onResponseTrue(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException;

    public void onResponseFalse(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException;

    public void onError(JSONArray jsonArray);

    public void onNoNetwork();

    public void onNetowkisOn();

    public void onCallFinish();
}
```

}

This class i have created to call sign in api

```
public class LoginApiCall {
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private BaseActivity activity;
private String
        email = "",
        password = "";
private OnServiceDoneListener listener;

public LoginApiCall(BaseActivity activity, String email, String password, OnServiceDoneListener listener) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.listener = listener;

    serviceCall();
}

private void serviceCall() {
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("email", email);
    hashMap.put("password", password);
    new ServiceCall(activity, Api.login, hashMap, new ServiceCall.IRestApiListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponseTrue(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            LoginModel loginModel = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).toString(), LoginModel.class);
            listener.onSuccess(true, loginModel);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponseFalse(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
            activity.setLogOut(activity, jsonArray);
            listener.onServiceFail(false,jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getInt("status"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("message"));

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(JSONArray jsonArray)  {
            try {
                listener.onServiceFail(false,jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getInt("status"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("message"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNoNetwork() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNetowkisOn() {
            showOrDissMissProgressDialog(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallFinish() {
            showOrDissMissProgressDialog(0);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * <p> Created by Jay <p/>
 * Show and dismiss progress dilaog
 * and alos initialied within the method
 *
 * @param flag eg. 1 show 0 hide
 */
private void showOrDissMissProgressDialog(int flag) {
    switch (flag) {
        case 0:
            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            progressDialog.setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.app_name));
            progressDialog.setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.please_wait));
            progressDialog.show();
            break;
    }

}

public interface OnServiceDoneListener {
public void onSuccess(boolean status, LoginModel loginModel);

public void onServiceFail(boolean status, int satatus,String response_message);
```

}
}

And now use this code to call this api from anywhere and in any activity

```
 new LoginApiCall(
                    LoginActivity.this,
                    JsSystemHelper.getStringFromView(edLoginEmail),
                    JsSystemHelper.getStringFromView(edLoginPassword),
                    new LoginApiCall.OnServiceDoneListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(boolean status, LoginModel loginModel) {
                           //RESPONSE TRUE

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onServiceFail(boolean status, int satatus, final String response_message) {
                          //RESPONSE FALSE

                            }

                        }

                    }
            );
        }
```